# Salesforce API SOQL - Exporting data as CSV

Tags: soql, csv

Is it possible via Salesforce SOQL API to get the results in CSV rather than JSON?

Example of the call I am making (via Postman for testing)

```
GET /services/data/v51.0/query?q=SELECT id,name,profile.name FROM User WHERE isactive = TRUE
```

I am trying to get this data as CSV instead of JSON but it doesn't seem possible.

Anything I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [REST API documentation on queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm?q=query) suggests that the only options here are XML and JSON (which you control by setting the `Accept` header to either `application/json` or `application/xml`, default is JSON)

If you need csv output, then you'll need to use something like Salesforce's Data Loader or the unofficial (but very useful) https://workbench.developerforce.com

Comment: Yeah, even tried a custom Accept header, no dice.